# Azure Active Directory (AAD) - User realm discovery failed

Tags: c#, webclient, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Sometimes we got this error while trying to authenticate user via `graph.windows.net` (api version 2013-11-08):

> user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery failed
>
> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure.

It's a WebAPI working on IIS at Windows Server 2012 R2. I've done some testing and at the same time application cannot download https://google.com (using `WebClient` class) but I can browse it with web browser on that current server.

Also I tried to ignore server certificate errors for whole application (code below) but it didn't help too.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{    
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
}
```

Here is my AAD connection code.

```
public GraphConnection CreateGraphConnection(string token)
{
    GraphSettings graphSettings = new GraphSettings();
    graphSettings.ApiVersion = "2013-11-08";
    graphSettings.GraphDomainName = "graph.windows.net";
    return new GraphConnection(token, Guid.NewGuid(), graphSettings);
}
```

Exception throws on this last line below

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("myauthorityUrl", null);
UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(aadUsername, password);
var authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientAppId, uc);
```

Comment: "I've done some testing and at the same time application cannot download https://google.com" -Then it's likely a configuration issue on your server and not an issue with AAD or the graph API.  Consider  updating your tags.